# Convex conjugacy and differentiating under the "sup" operator

Tags: statistics, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I am working through example 3.10 (page 71) of a [book on variational inference](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ewainwrig/Papers/WaiJor08_FTML.pdf) in statistics and the authors discuss taking the gradient of the following function with respect to $\mu$:
$$
A^*(\mu) = \sup_{\theta \in \mathbb{R}} \{\, \theta \cdot \mu - \log(1 + \exp(\theta))\,\}.
$$

They state that the stationary condition $\nabla_\mu A^*(\mu) = 0$ is attained at the location $\mu = \exp(\theta)/(1+\exp(\theta))$.

I'm wondering how to derive this since $\nabla A^*(\mu)$ seems to require pushing the gradient operator through the "sup" operator which has no closed form and which may not even be differentiable!

Any guidance or trick for how this stationary condition is derived is very much appreciated

Comment: Fix $\mu$. If $\mu <0$ then the $\sup$ is infinite, if $\mu = 0$ then the $\sup $ is zero (but not attained) and if $\mu>0$ there is a unique $\max$ which occurs at the above point. In general there is no reason to presume that that the dual is differentiable (or even finite) everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be confusing something here. The authors construct the **conjugate function** of $A(\theta)$, noted as $A^*(\mu)$. In order to do so, they solve the maximization problem $(3.47)$, which is done by setting $\nabla_{\theta}A=0$. They then analyze the solution of $\nabla_{\theta}A=0$ for different values of of $\mu$, which they denote as $\theta(\mu)$.

They arrive to the conclusion that $A^*(\mu)=\mu\log\mu+(1-\mu)\log(1-\mu)$ over the domain $\mu\in[0,1]$. When $\mu<0$ or $\mu>1$ the original conjugate maximization problem is unbounded, therefore $\mu$ is restricted to that line interval.

Comment: Thanks @iarbel84. I don't see how the solution of $\nabla_{\theta} = 0$ gives the solution to problem (3.47). Specifically, problem (3.47) is a maximization over $\mu$ whereas $\nabla_{\theta} = 0$ is an optimization over $\theta$. Are you able to elaborate here?

Answer (score 1):

Let $A(\theta)=\log(1+\exp(\theta))$. Then, $A$ is a proper, continuous and convex function.

In this case, it holds $(\partial A)^{-1} = \partial A^*$, where $\partial A$ stands for the subdifferential of $A$
(see Corollary 16.30 in "Convex Analysis and Monotone Operator Theory in Hilbert Spaces, 2nd edition").
By using this formula, we obtain $\nabla A^*(\mu)= (\nabla A)^{-1}(\mu)$.

Comment: Thanks @kumegon. Does $(\partial A)^{-1}$ denote the preimage of $\partial A$ ?

Comment: @ted Yes. Note that both of $\partial A$ and $(\partial A)^{-1}$ are set-valued mappings.

Comment: Thanks again @kumegon. And to confirm, you mean set-valued in the same way that the subgradient is set-valued?

Comment: @ted Yes, that's right.